# gatt connection primary discoery: request not supported error

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to communicated between two devices with low energy bluetooth support with gatt profile. I am using gatttool to connect. I observed (with btmon) that while connecting both device request for the primary discovery by group type request. Then both devices sends "Request Not Supported" to primary discovery as error. These devices have bluez stack running and the same request is responded properly later. I dont get this problem if this the bug. I need to get discover primary service while connecting with peripheral.